# Using the BDG inequality to show a process is uniformly integrable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

For a *BSDE* :

$$y_t = \xi + \int_{t}^{T}g_0(s)ds - \int_{t}^{T}z_sdB_s$$

Which has a fixed $\xi \in L^2(\mathscr{F}_T)$ and $g_0(\cdot)$ satisfying $E(\int_{0}^{T}|g_0(t)|dt)^2 < \infty$.
There exists a unique pair of process $(y., z.)\in L_{\mathscr{F}}^2(0,T;R^{1+d})$ satisfies the BSDE shown before.

How to use the Burkholder-Davis-Gundy (BDG) inequality to prove the following inequality?

$$E[\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} |y_t|^2]< \infty$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $g=0$. The quadratic variation of $y$ is given by:
$$\langle y\rangle_t = \int_t^T z_s^2 ds \leq \int_0^T z_s^2 ds $$
The BDG inequality tells you that, for some $C>0$, we have:
$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|y_t|^2 \right] \leq C \mathbb{E} \left[ \langle y\rangle_0 \right] \leq C \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^T z_s^2 ds \right] < \infty$$
where the last inequality follows by the assumption imposed on $z$.

If $g \neq 0$, then an application of the triangle inequality plus the conditions on $g$ and $\xi$ guarantee the same result.

---

Alternatively, one could use Doob's maximal inequality to get:
$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|y_t|^2 \right] \leq 4\mathbb{E}(|Y_T|^2) = 4\mathbb{E}({\xi^2}) < \infty$$